# My git clone is not working and the command is getting skipped or stopping there only

Tags: git, github

```
srinj@LAPTOP-BN07C645 MINGW64 /c/Angular (master)
$ git clone https://github.com/Mr-Prince16/psl-exit.git
Cloning into 'psl-exit'...

srinj@LAPTOP-BN07C645 MINGW64 /c/Angular (master)
```

Whenever I am doing git clone any repository it says cloning into and then skips the command

I have tried everything possible. Uninstalled git and reinstalled then also removed my credentials from credentials manager and then tried to clone using personal access token also but not working.